# Build error with System.Web switching a C# project over from AnyCPU to x64

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, system.web

I have a Visual Studio (2013) C# project that builds fine on `AnyCPU` is failing to build when I change the platform target to `x64`. This is on .NET 2. The error I get is

> An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll.

I'm struggling to find what I should do here. I have tried re-adding Sustem.Web and resources I have read indicate that this reference should work for either platform (I presume it is itself `AnyCPU`). I feel like I am missing something very obvious here...

Comment: How did you've changed platform target?

Comment: @SeM Through project properties ->Build -> Platform target

Comment: In same page, what Platform selected (not platform target, this one on top).

Comment: @SeM Active (Any CPU). Don't currently have a x64 Platform present in the dropdown but will try adding one

Comment: @SeM Added a x64 build config platform but made no difference. (Wouldn't expect it to, really)

Comment: System.Web must *never* be loaded from that directory, it belongs in the GAC (c:\windows\assembly).  Nothing that a disk format can't fix, also a good way to get rid of the need to target 2.0

Comment: @HansPassant I do definitely need to target 2.0. Are you sure about the directory being wrong? This is a normal VS installation with no customizations. If this is corrupt, I have no idea how it could have become so. I also checked with a colleague and his is pointing to the same directory.

Comment: 100% sure.  There are no breadcrumbs in the question to guess how this could have gone so wrong, I've never seen a prior case of this going wrong either.  You'll need to show us a Fuslogvw.exe trace to move this ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was caused by an `AfterBuild` event in the .csproj file that was invoking SGEN. Disabling "Generate serialization assembly" and removing this `AfterBuild` event resolved it.